# Is there a browser extension which can copy a webpage snippet/clip/scnapshot to clipboard

Tags: google-chrome, clipboard

I have to save links to web pages into a google drive document. What I want is to copy simple webpage snippet, similar to the one this G+ extension button does, to clipboard. One picture and page title as a link.

I was looking for many days now and I still couldn't find anything which does the same thing. In the end the thing I came up with is to hit the G+ button and copy contents of the popup.

I am wondering if anybody knows how can this be done right?

Thanks in advance,
BR,
Yuriy

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any (easy to find) Google Chrome extensions for screen capturing that can copy to clipboard, but you can download snippets of a webpage to disk using [Awesome Screenshot: Capture & Annotate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce?hl=en)

## Features

【Capture 】

 1. Capture or clip selected area, or all visible portion, or entire page

 2. Support  PNG format

 3  Support  horizontal scroll when capturing

【Annotate & Edit】

 1.Annotate it with rectangles, circles, arrows, lines and text

 2.Crop and scroll & Show crop area dimension

 
 3. Use eraser to hide sensitive information 

 4. Copy the screenshot  and paste it to gmail etc. Support Windows and Linux.

【Save & Share】

1. Save to Local

2. One-click to upload to awesomescreenshot.com and get a shareable link 

3. Support Google Drive (Gdrive) Now.

 
3. Save very large image, by pass the 2M limit. No crash any more.

## Note

This extension is the best around; [Screen Capture (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capture-by-google/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg?hl=en) has been reported not to work on more recent versions of Chrome (34)

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have already tried this. Unfortunately it can only make screenshots, which I can perfectly do with MS Snipping Tool. WHat I really wanted is a tool which can parse the page name in addition to a screenshot.